# Prime ideals in real quadratic fields being principal depends only on the residue class mod D of its norm?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, characters

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field of discriminant $D$. Then it is well known that each prime $p \in \mathbb Z$ splits completely in $\mathcal O_K$ if and only if $\chi_D(p)=1$. Splitting completely means that $(p)=PP'$ with $P \ne P'$ being prime ideals of $\mathcal O_K$.

Now I found out by doing a computer check that for completely splitting primes with $p \equiv q \pmod D$ we have that the corresponding ideal $P$ is principal if and only if $Q$ is. Is that actually true? How would you prove that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H$ be the class field of $K$ (in particular, it is totally real) and $p$ be a prime number that splits in $K$, write $p=PP’$. We have a canonical isomorphism $Gal(H/K) \cong Cl(K)$; fot this isomorphism, $P$ is trivial in $Cl(K)$ iff $P$ is totally split in $H$ iff $Frob_P \in Gal(H/K)$ is trivial.

Now $Frob_P\in Gal(H/K)$ is the element $g$ of this group such that $g$ preserves all primes of $H$ above $P$, and $g$ acts on the residue field at $P$ by $x \longmapsto x^{N(P)}=x^p$.

But $Frob_P \in Gal(H/\mathbb{Q})$ as well, and because $N(P)=p$, it is a Frobenius at one (any) of the primes of $H$ above $P$, so its conjugacy class is that of $Frob_p \in Gal(H/\mathbb{Q})$.

In other words, for primes $p$ totally split in $K$, the “splitting prime” is principal in $K$ iff $Frob_p \in Gal(H/\mathbb{Q})$ is trivial.

Let $C=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i\pi/D})$, then $C \supset K$ and $C/K$ is abelian. Consider a prime $p$ totally split in $K$, and $P$ one of its factors. Then $Frob_p \in Gal(HC/\mathbb{Q})$ lies in fact in $Gal(HC/K)$ (which is abelian), and is a Frobenius at $P$.

Now, we have an injection $Gal(HC/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow Gal(H/\mathbb{Q}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/(D))^{\times}$, with image $U$, mapping $Frob_p$ to $Frob_p$ on the first coordinate and $p$ mod $D$ on the second one.

By Cebotarev, the conjugacy classes of images of Frobenius cover $U$. Note that $p$ being split in $K$ can be seen as a constraint on $p$ mod $D$ – let $S$ be the corresponding subgroup.

Your question thus amounts to: given $g,h \in U$, such that $p_2(g)=p_2(h)$ corresponds to a split prime, must we have $p_1(g)=e$ iff $p_1(h)=e$? The answer is yes iff for each $s \in S$, $p_1(p_2^{-1}(s) \cap U)$ is the identity iff it contains the identity.

In other words, if $U’ \subset U$ is the (abelian) image of $Gal(HC/K)$, when your answer is yes, $p_1(\ker{p_2})$ is trivial, and, by translation, $p_1$ is trivial on the fibers of $p_2$. This condition is also sufficient to yield a positive answer to your question.

In other words: your statement is equivalent to the following claim: in $Gal(HC/K)$, the class of an element in $Gal(C/K)$ determines the class of this element in $Gal(H/K)$, ie $Gal(HC/K) \rightarrow Gal(C/K)$ injective, is $H \subset C$.

In other words, when your statement holds, $H/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian. But we have an exact sequence of groups $0 \rightarrow Cl(K) \rightarrow Gal(H/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow 1$ where the conjugation action is by $-1$ – in particular, if $H/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian, then $Cl(K)$ is a $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space.

So this shouldn’t work for the number field 2.2.229.1 (see the LMFDB – it is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{229})$), and whose class field should be 6.6.12008989.1 (see the LMFDB again – it’s not spelled out but it has the right degree, signature and ramification). Maybe you can check this case?

A particular case where the result holds is when $O_K$ is a PID, so that $H=K$. This happens for many “small” real quadratic fields, which could be the cases that you’ve studied?

Comment: Thank you for your long and good answer. I will check the case $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{229})$. Of course the statement is trivially true if $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID. Therefore, I checked the statement only in number fields with class number $h_K>1$. For example in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10})$.

Comment: You were right. In $\mathcal O_K(\sqrt{229})$ the prime $p=2749$ splits into two principal ideals where the prime $q=5039$ splits into two non-principal ideals. We have $p\equiv q\equiv 1 \pmod D$. By the way, $D=229$ is the smallest prime discriminant of a real quadratic number field of class number greater $1$.

Comment: Thank you for checking! In fact, the proof gives a necessary condition for the result to hold: the class group of $K$ must have exponent $1$ or $2$ (otherwise $H/\mathbb{Q}$ is not abelian). I checked in the LMFDB: the only discriminant smaller than $229$ where this condition fails is $5 \cdot 29=145$. I don’t know if the condition is sufficient: $H$ will be abelian so contained in *some* cyclotomic extension, but how do we know that it is contained in $C$? Maybe this information is somehow contained in ramification indices…

Comment: The "first" real quadratic field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ measured by *squarefree* $d$ (not by discriminant $D$!) where the class number $h$ is not a $2$-power is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{79})$, with $D = 4 \cdot 79 = 316$: its class number is $3$. This is also the first real quadratic field measured by squarefree $d$ where the class number is odd.  So it might be interesting to look for counterexamples there as well.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain for how many real quadratic fields (up to what discriminant or up to what squarefree $d$) was the computer check you mentioned in your question?

Comment: @KCd I think the first real quadratic number field ordered by squarefree $d$ with odd class number is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ ;-)

Comment: @Aphelli I checked $\mathbb Q (\sqrt{145})$ as well and found $p=1451$ and $q=3191$. Both are $1$ mod $145$ but above $p$ lie two non-principal ideal where above $q$ lie two principal ones.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain  yeah, you got me there.  I meant "odd class number bigger than 1" of course: ordered by squarefree $d$, the first with class number $3$ is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{79})$, the first with class number $5$ is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{401})$, the first with class number $7$ is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{577})$, and the first with class number $9$ is $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{1129})$ for cyclic class group of order $9$ and $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{32009})$ for noncyclic class group of order $9$.

Comment: @KCd It looks like you know as well how to operate SageMath ;-)

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain nope, but I do know how to use other computer algebra systems.

Comment: @KCd Which one?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain PARI.  yes, I am aware it is part of Sage.